# Ember.js template not iterating over {{#each}}

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember.js handlebars template running an `{{#each}}` loop to iterate over a returned store data. There is only one record in the store, so I would expect this code to be executed 1 time. However, it is not executing at all and I can't seem to figure out why. Here is the .hbs code:

```
{{#each model.framework as |framework|}} 
  {{#paper-item noink=true}}
    <p class="question">
      {{paper-input label="Question" required=true value=detail}}
    </p>
    <p class="option">
      {{#paper-radio value="text" selected=type}}Text{{/paper-radio}} 
      {{#paper-radio value="radio" selected=type}}Options{{/paper-radio}} 

      {{#paper-button action=(action "newQuestion" framework.id) raised=true}}Add Question{{/paper-button}}
    </p>
  {{/paper-item}} 
{{/each}}
```

This `{{#each}}` loop should be rendering data from this query on my store (from my routes.js file for this page):

```
model(params) {
  var id = params.framework_id;
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    question: this.store.query('question', {orderBy: 'framework', equalTo: id}),
    framework: this.store.find('framework', id)
  })
}
```

And I know the routing and querying of the store are working correctly because the framework I'm trying to iterate on is in the Data store via Ember inspector:

[Ember.js Inspector Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2U41y.png)

There are other `{{#each}}` loops on the page (for the "question" store) working without issue. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.framework` is a single object that you retrieve from your backend using `store.find`:

```
return Ember.RSVP.hash({
  question: this.store.query('question', {orderBy: 'framework', equalTo: id}),
  framework: this.store.find('framework', id) // <-- This returns an object
})
```

However, as [Ember Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each) explain:

> The {{#each}} helper loops over elements in a collection.

Which means **you cannot loop over a single object because it is not a collection**.
You need to remove the `{{each}}` helper and use `model.framework` instead of `framework`:

```
{{#paper-item noink=true}}
  <p class="question">
    {{paper-input label="Question" required=true value=detail}}
  </p>
  <p class="option">
    {{#paper-radio value="text" selected=type}}Text{{/paper-radio}}
    {{#paper-radio value="radio" selected=type}}Options{{/paper-radio}}

    {{#paper-button action=(action "newQuestion" model.framework.id) raised=true}}Add Question{{/paper-button}}
  </p>
{{/paper-item}}
```

If you want to loop over object properties instead, you can check out the [each-in helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers.html#method_each-in)